# MapView Snapshot for Parse Geopoints

Tags: ios, parse-platform, mkmapview

I wan't to set a fixed map view for every posts, so that when the user clicks a cell and is taken to the detail view, there is a map displaying the location of the event. However the user should not be able to scroll, zoom, or pan. I am using Parse geopoints to show each event location, how can I display this preferred fixed map for each individual geopoint?

Comment: This repository does something similar in ruby: https://github.com/johnnyrodgers/slack-map